# Texture Painting Not Appearing In Render Mode

Tags: rendering, texturing, texture-painting

I've modeled a medieval Tankard here. It has been UV unwrapped and a wood texture applied to it. After doing so, I decided it would look nicer if the bulged portions were made of metal instead of wood. I opened texture paint mode, found a metal texture and attempted to paint the area.
[image]

But when rendered it does not appear[image]

Decently new to Blender and am not sure how to fix. This is my first post on Stack Exchange

Comment: Looks like updated paint missing in render could be fixed if you saved image you painted it on before rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Needed to save the painted texture as a new image